# Adding a "Big Icon" to the Joomla admin dashboard

Tags: joomla, administration

I've done this befor but with all my memory, search efforts and logic failing I can't figure out how to add a new "Big Icon" link on the main dashboard of the Joomla administration.
What file am i looking to change?
I'm sitting on a fresh install of 1.5.15

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you mean addin a new "big Icon" to the control panel of the Joomla administration dashboard?

image-example: http://i49.tinypic.com/9ampmq.png

(image is in spanish, just an example)
Anyway, if that is what you're looking for:

1. Check the **mod_quickicon** folder inside of /administrator/modules/.
2. Inside, you should see **mod_quickicon.php**, open it.
3. Scroll down and you'll find a `<div id="cpanel">...</div>`
4. Here's where you make the magic happen. Just copy one of the quick-icons, i.e.

`$link = 'index.php?option=com_media';
  quickiconButton( $link, 'icon-48-media.png', JText::_( 'Media Manager' ) );`

.. and edit it according to what you need/want. I guess you know what I mean, but just to make sure, you probably want to change the image, the *$link* (for that you'll have to create a custom folder if you wanna keep it clean, such as "com_whateveryouwant".

I hope this helps.
You could also just download this extension.. but it'll be boring:
--sorry can't post more links, if you're interested, write me back--

Chris.

Comment: Bear in mind that this hacks the Joomla core; your modifications will be subject to patches. However, I don't believe that there's a way to do it otherwise. If you plan ahead, you can double check the patch files before applying and make sure that they don't overwrite this file.

Comment: Of course, it's a joomla hack; this is something any user must and will do with any CMS (maybe not all, but with most). And regarding the patching: Yes, you'll have to keep your local files/folders in order so that after a patch you're able to upload them back up in no-time ;)

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to make new Quickicon plugin. The simpliest way is to inspire in Extensionupdate or Joomlaupdate Quickicon plugin.

1. Copy the directory of some plugin, rename the directory to your own `Quickicon` Plugin name, edit the file in what you want ... the base thing is that the plugin must return Icon Definition array
2. Need to add to SQL DB do `#_extensions` (# is db prefix) new line of code defining that the `plg_guickicon_ownplugin` is there (again, inspire in `Joomlaupdate/Extensionupdate` plugin SQL record)

And that's all, no hacking needed, just make own plugin for Quickicon module

Answer (score 0):

The file is a module, you can create a module and assign it to the position of 'icons'.